# Display only not null records in model

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, code-first

This is the method in controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
{
    //CourseCategory courseCategory = db.CourseCategories.Find(id);
    CourseCategory courseCategory = db.CourseCategories.Include(s => s.Files).SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == id);
    if (courseCategory == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(courseCategory);
}
```

This is view:

```
<tr>
    <td style="color: #3399FF; font-weight: bold;">
        <div class="display-label">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.courseField)
        </div>
    </td>

    <td>
        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.courseField)
        </div>
    </td>
```

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.courseSubject)

```
   <td>
        <div class="display-field">
           @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.courseSubject)
        </div>
   </td>
```

This is how I retrieve model data into table. I want to hide the label and its containing tr tag if the record is empty. I don't want to show null records. How can I do that?

Comment: You should return filtered model from controller/ If possible you can prevent fetching `nulls` from DB too!

Comment: Can I do that within the method of my controller? If there is a null record I want hide the entire row. so that should be need to do at the view i guess. Isn't it ??

Comment: All 3 ways you can hide it, 1) you can select those values which are not null from DB, 2) you can return model by filtering it by lambda expressions, 3) You can check values before generating `tr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
@if(model.courseField!="" && model.courseField!=null)
{
  <tr>
      <td style="color: #3399FF; font-weight: bold;">
          <div class="display-label">
           @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.courseField)
          </div>
      </td>

      <td>
          <div class="display-field">
           @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.courseField)
          </div>
     </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Similarly for `courseSubject`!! Just append it if value is present in  `model attribute`

Comment: Thanks @Guruprasad Rao. :)

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)